# T&& in templated function and class

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I've just stumbled upon that `T&&` in class and function means different things.
In function:

```
template<class T> void f(T&& t){};   // t is R or L-value
...
int i=0; 
f(i);   // t in f is lvalue
f(42);  // t in f is rvalue
```

In class:

```
template<class T> 
struct S { 
       S(T&& t){}  // t is only R-value? 
};
...
int i;
S<int> ss(i);   // compile error - cannot bind lvalue to ‘int&&’
```

Does this means that if we have`T&& t` in class, than `t` will be only rvalue?
Can some one point me where I can get more info about this?
Does it means that I need to write two method overloads for L and R-values?

**ANSWER**
As Alf's example shows, `t` in function and class can be Lvalue or Rvalue.

Comment: `t` can be an rvalue reference or an lvalue reference, but in both cases, `t` is an lvalue. Every function parameter is an lvalue, regardless of type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `T` is deduced from the actual argument. The main use for that particular combination is **perfect forwarding**. In the class template `T` is not deduced, it must be specified.

E.g., this compiles nicely with both g++ and msvc:

```
template<class T> 
struct S { 
       S(T&& t){}
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    S< int& > ss(i);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You're dealing with template argument deduction here.

By using `f` *without* explicitly defining the template argument, C++ compilers now must decide what the template argument type `T` is from the parameters you pass it.

The rules for template argument deduction with `&&` types are special to allow for perfect forwarding. When you use `f(i)`, the `T` is deduced as `T&`. Thus, the parameter `t` is of type `T& &&`, which collapses to `T&`. However, when you use `f(42)`, the type `T` is deduced as `T&&`, and thus `t` is `T&& &&`, which collapses to `T&&`.

Once you *force* `T` to be a specific type, all that effectively goes away. The collapsing can still happen, but because you used `S<int>`, then `t` will be of type `int&&`. `S<int> ss(i)` is effectively the equivalent of `f<int>(i)`, which is also not legal. And since template argument deduction only works with functions and not types, you have to do something like this for `S` if you want perfect forwarding:

```
template<class T> 
struct S { 
    template<class U>
    S(U&& t){}
};
```

Of course, you can use SFINAE methods and template metaprogramming to ensure that the constructor template can only be instantiated if the basic type of `T` and `U` are the same.